# Anything opened in Preview shows for less than a second and disappears

Tags: preview, bug

I upgraded to macOS Ventura from macOS Catalina last year, and since then I've had the issue of Preview not working. Whenever I open something (a PNG image, a JPEG image, a PDF, whatever), I see it for less than a second and it just disappears. I would really appreciate some help. I tried googling this, but couldn't find anything that works.

[image: The image shows and then immediately disappears]

Comment: If you open the image file not from Kitty but from Terminal does it work? Likewise if it is opened from within Preview does it work?

Comment: @SteveM Nope, I just tried everything again just to be sure. It never works.

Comment: What about QuickLook? Does thathave the same problem? Or opening images in Safari? Have you got lots of additional "utilities" and "helpers" running in the background? Quit/uninstall them all and test. Or try a fresh user account as a test.